# Mass regex search-and-replace BETWEEN patterns

Tags: regex, shell

I have a directory with a bunch of text files, all of which follow this structure:

```
...
 - Some random number of list items of random text
 - And even more of it

PATTERN_A (surrounded by empty lines)

 - Again, some list items of random text
 - Which does look similar as the first batch

PATTERN_B (surrounded by empty lines)

 - And even more some random text
....
```

And I need to run a replace operation (let's say, I need to prepend CCC at the beginning of the line, just after the dash) on only those "list items", which are between PATTERN_A and PATTERN_B. The problem is they aren't really much  different from the text above PATTERN_A, or below PATTERN_B, so an ordinary regex can't really catch them without also affecting the remaining text.

So, my question would be, what tool and what regex should I use to perform that replacement?

(Just in case, I'm fine with Vim, and I can collect those files in a QuickFix for a further `:cdo`, for example. I'm not that good with awk, unfortunately, and absolutely bad with Perl :))

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the sample output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your questions, you can do so quite easily with a pattern-range selection and the general substitution form with `sed` (stream editor). For example, in your case:

```
$ sed '/PATTERN_A/,/PATTERN_B/s/^\([ ]*-\)/\1CCC/' file
 - Some random number of list items of random text
 - And even more of it

PATTERN_A (surrounded by empty lines)

 -CCC Again, some list items of random text
 -CCC Which does look similar as the first batch

PATTERN_B (surrounded by empty lines)

 - And even more some random text
```

(**note:** to substitute in place within the file add the `-i` option, and to create a backup of the original add `-i.bak` which will save the original file as `file.bak`)

**Explanation**

- `/PATTERN_A/,/PATTERN_B/` - select lines between `PATTERN_A` and `PATTERN_B`
- `s/^\([ ]*-\)/\1CCC/` - substitute (general form `'s/find/replace/'`) where `find` is from beginning of line `^` capturing text between `\(...\)` that contains `[ ]*-` (any number of spaces and a hyphen) and then `replace` with `\1` (called a *backreference* that contains all characters you captured with the capture group `\(...\)`) and appending `CCC` to its end.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions or if I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Thanks, David! Simultaneously with you, I've just remembered that Vim, actually, allows exactly the same thing, selecting a range by indicating search patterns, like this `:/PATTERN_A/, /PATTERN_B/s/\(^ \+-\)/\1 CCC/`. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Yes, vim allows regex substitutions as well. If there is the possibility that your file begins with `tab` characters and not just `spaces` before the `'-'`, you can change the literal zero-or-more space `[ ]*` characters to zero-or-more *whitespace* using `\s*` instead.

Answer (score 1):

With Perl also, you can get the results

```
> perl -pe ' { s/^(\s*-)/\1CCC/g if /PATTERN_A/../PATTERN_B/ } ' mass_replace.txt
...
 - Some random number of list items of random text
 - And even more of it

PATTERN_A (surrounded by empty lines)

 -CCC Again, some list items of random text
 -CCC Which does look similar as the first batch

PATTERN_B (surrounded by empty lines)

 - And even more some random text
....
>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks very readable, actually :) (do like the usage of `if`, will try to use something like this in the future)